# Ler matriz de um arquivo na diagonal

Tags: c, arquivo

Olá!

Tenho um arquivo de tamanho fixo que possui uma matriz de caracteres aleatórios. Porem estou com dificuldade para usar o fseek e o fread pare ler o arquivo na diagonal.

Para explicar o problema, preciso fazer uma espécie de caça palavras que busca as palavras na horizontal, vertical e diagonal.

exemplo super reduzido da matriz:

```
nwlrbbmqbh
cdarzowkky
hiddqscdxr
jmowfrxsjy
bldbefsarc
bynecdyggx
xpklorelln
mpapqfwkho
pkmcoqhnwn
kuewhsqmgb
```

OBS: eu não posso joga-la na memória.

Comment: Não seria mais fácil ler o arquivo inteiro de uma vez e então ficar fazendo buscas em memória?

Comment: Uma amostra desse arquivo ajudaria muito.

Comment: Eu não posso jogar o arquivo todo na memória.

@Lacobus eu editei ali com um exemplo bem reduzido, mas é basicamente uma matriz de ZxZ com caracteres aleatórios

Comment: Se você não pode ler o arquivo inteiro na memoria, não seria possivel ter apenas as ultimas ~30 linhas na memoria e fazer a procura somente nestes dados?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue um programa capaz de ler palavras dispostas na horizontal, vertical e diagonal em um caça-palavras contido em um arquivo texto.

As palavras podem ser acessadas por meio de suas coordenadas:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


typedef enum {
    eHorizontal,
    eVertical,
    eDiagonal
} orientacao_t;


char obter_letra( int col, int linha, FILE * pf )
{
    char buf[1024] = {0};

    rewind(pf);

    while( 0 <= linha-- )
        fgets( buf, sizeof(buf), pf );

    return buf[ col ];
}


char * obter_palavra( char * p, int col, int linha, int tam, orientacao_t or, FILE * pf )
{
    int i = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < tam; i++ )
    {
        switch( or )
        {
            case eHorizontal :
                p[i] = obter_letra( col + i, linha, pf );
                break;

            case eVertical:
                p[i] = obter_letra( col, linha + i, pf );
                break;

            case eDiagonal:
                p[i] = obter_letra( col + i, linha + i, pf );
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    p[tam] = '\0';

    return p;
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    char palavra[50] = {0};
    FILE * pf = NULL;

    pf = fopen( argv[1], "r" );

    printf( "Palavra 1: %s\n", obter_palavra( palavra,  11,  2,  8, eDiagonal,   pf ) );
    printf( "Palavra 2: %s\n", obter_palavra( palavra,   7, 18, 10, eHorizontal, pf ) );
    printf( "Palavra 3: %s\n", obter_palavra( palavra,   5,  8,  8, eVertical,   pf ) );
    printf( "Palavra 4: %s\n", obter_palavra( palavra,   10, 6, 8,  eDiagonal, pf ) );
    printf( "Palavra 5: %s\n", obter_palavra( palavra,   9, 16,  4, eHorizontal, pf ) );
    printf( "Palavra 6: %s\n", obter_palavra( palavra,   18,  16,  4, eVertical,   pf ) );

    fclose(pf);

    return 0;
}
```

Arquivo de teste contendo as palavras `VERTICAL`, `HORIZONTAL`, `DIAGONAL`, `GATO`, `CACHORRO` e `RATO`:

```
CAQIXCBXXJMDVRANWPMT
YGOQZMQWVKMMJMSIAQDI
XFXOBRWILQJDJYORKGWC
UARIHCBJSDTLIEBSETOH
QSLOCAWZFUYXBASBJTCC
NLJDHZMWYMLVPVGWPNAZ
BBTOCWHEYVCDNGPOLHXO
SDICESRPTQPARRLNNSHZ
XMSKYVIGVDZLCEBBIAOW
UTZABEBHKJNTEHFNPILH
GINPIRMZTJJVLIOZHRRE
NJFRQTLRHBQOSNQRIWOX
CBJTPIEDNWBJKGDJRTIC
SRTWSCSPWFHEMKYGYOXU
OYSCYAPEDMABBFJBZSZN
RQVSILWPWOGNREWNKHHE
JBXFOFFYGGATOJLUMORV
FNVLDATMISHLTVIZEDAL
DZADHEZHORIZONTALXTC
MXOPRHRNNNBXMZNHUOOG
```

Saída:

```
Palavra 1: DIAGONAL
Palavra 2: HORIZONTAL
Palavra 3: VERTICAL
Palavra 4: CACHORRO
Palavra 5: GATO
Palavra 6: RATO
```

Comment: Creio que se, por acaso, a linha tiver mais de 1024 caracteres sua resposta vai detectar como "mudança de linha" algo prematuro, concorda? Também achei sua solução com muitas leituras. O problema garante que as linhas tenham todas as mesmas dimensões dentro do mesmo arquivo, então bastaria procurar pela quebra de linha a primeira vez, para então poder navegar com `fseek`, não?